# DI example in Jersey 2.34 with Google Guice 4.2.3

Tags: jersey, guice

Please suggest a good example of implementing Dependency Injection using GUICE in a Jersey RESTful API application. Examples on many websites are very old (Implemented somewhere between 2011-2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer that explains all the logic and solves various problems/conflicts which arise when GUICE is used with Jersey.

Have a look at below example

http://www.zakariaamine.com/2017-12-11/how-to-use-guice-jersey-2